# Is it possible to connect to Websphere MQ using .NET and a certificate from the windows certificate store?

Tags: .net, ssl, certificate, ibm-mq

The Redbook documentation details out creating a `.sto` file using `amqmcert`, but is it possible for a .NET MQ client to just use a certificate out of the Windows certificate store (system store, ie, MMC->Add/Remove Snap-In->Certificates->Computer Account)?

Answer (score 1):

Not with current versions of WebSphere MQ. As of V6.0, WMQ began using KDB files for certs rather than the Windows cert store.  This provides a common set of tooling across all the distributed platforms supported by WebSphere MQ, as well as reducing the amount of platform-specific code.  If you'd like to request that WMQ once again support the Windows cert store, please create a Request For Enhancement (or upvote one if it already exists) at the [RFE Community](http://ibm.co/P5TVP3).

**UPDATE**
The Infocenter currently mentions some use of Windows Certificate Store with the XMS classes for .Net connecting to SIBus.  This is incorrect and will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

IBM MQv8 .NET Client now supports Windows key store. You can use Windows key store for client applications for secure connections to queue manager. More details [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q120370_.htm).